# Copy postgis data from CSV files in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgis

I need to import name and geometry data from a CSV file to PostgreSQL.

The `individuals.csv` file format is as below:

```
first_name,last_name,location
Russell,Wolff,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[73.0786759127481,29.730356801638685]},"properties":{}}
```

All the geometry types are of `"type":"Point"` in the CSV file and the file has around 500K+ records. Above is just 1 record example.

I have created below table to store the data:

```
CREATE TABLE individuals (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(255),
  last_name VARCHAR(255),
  location_point GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326) -- Use GEOGRAPHY data type for storing points
);
```

I have written below `plpgsql` function to do the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_csv_data(directory text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    file_name text;
    csv_data json;
begin
    -- Loop through GeoJSON files in the specified directory
    FOR file_name IN 
        SELECT *
        FROM pg_ls_dir(directory)
    loop
        IF file_name LIKE '%.csv' then

        RAISE NOTICE 'GeoJSON data: %', pg_read_file('path/to/individuals.csv');
        
        COPY individuals(first_name, last_name, location_point)
        FROM 'path/to/individuals.csv'
        CSV HEADER;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So the idea is that I pass the `directory` to the function containing multiple CSV files and then `COPY` the data from each file to the table individuals. So I am running a loop over each `file_name`.

Now when I run this function:

`SELECT public.insert_csv_data('path/to/directory');`

I have a

`RAISE NOTICE 'GeoJSON data: %', pg_read_file('path/to/individuals.csv');`
which is path to individuals.csv file it prints the data correctly, which is as below:

```
GeoJSON data: first_name,last_name,location
Russell,Wolff,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[73.0786759127481,29.730356801638685]},"properties":{}}
```

I get an **error**:

```
SQL Error [22P04]: ERROR: extra data after last expected column
  Where: COPY individuals, line 2: "Russell,Wolff,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[73.0786759127481,29.730356..."
SQL statement "COPY individuals(first_name, last_name, location_point)
        FROM 'path/to/individuals.csv'
        CSV HEADER"
PL/pgSQL function insert_csv_data(text) line 15 at SQL statement
```

My question is:

1. Right now I am running the COPY command with FROM as the hardcoded path of 1 file. How I can dynamically substitute the path of each file_name something like `directory || '/' || file_name` in the COPY FROM so that data is copied from that file and then subsequent files?
2. I need to extract the `geometry` key after `,` from the CSV and then insert it into column `location_point GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326)`. How I can do that?

I am stuck here, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `location` is a nested structure and CSV does not do nested. You will not be able to pull the `POINT` data out using `COPY`. You will need to preprocess the data to get it into a flat format that CSV/COPY  can deal with.

Comment: I think the error is because copy is treating the commas in the geometry as delimiters. I would be tempted to copy the files in to a temp table with one column, then use some regular expressions to extract the columns.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I am running the COPY command with FROM as the hardcoded path of 1 file. How I can dynamically substitute the path of each file_name something like `directory || '/' || file_name` in the COPY FROM so that data is copied from that file and then subsequent files?

You can use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in your PL/pgSQL block:

```sql
do $f$
declare 
    v_file text:=concat('/tmp/','individuals.csv');
begin 
    execute format('copy test from %1$L', v_file);
end $f$;
```

Passing a `text` variable directly to `copy` command won't work, neither will calling a `text`-returning function like `concat()` or `||`. The command expects a literal and the dynamic SQL above lets you first execute the function, then evaluate the variable holding its result before passing it as a literal.

---

> I need to extract the geometry key after , from the CSV and then insert it into column location_point GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326). How I can do that?

Because of the structure of your file, the `copy` command:

```sql
COPY individuals(first_name, last_name, location_point) 
FROM 'path/to/individuals.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

is equivalent to this sort of `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO individuals(
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    location_point )
VALUES (
    'Russell',
    'Wolff',
    '{"type":"Feature"',
    '"geometry":{"type":"Point"',
    '"coordinates":[73.0786759127481',
    '29.730356801638685]}',
    '"properties":{}}' );
```

Which would throw an error; there are more values than columns because [`copy` defaults to `delimiter ','`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.6).

> `DELIMITER`
> Specifies the character that separates columns within each row (line) of the file. **The default is a tab character in text format, a comma in `CSV` format.** This must be a single one-byte character.

Unless you use proper string quoting, it splits the input lines wherever it finds a comma, so in your case it cuts up the last field into multiple pieces. To fix this, you can

1. Run your data through an intermediate table that accepts the `location` in five parts, then reassemble it using [`concat_ws(',',...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.5.1.1.1). Use `quote '~'` (or any character unused in the file) to override default `quote '"'` - otherwise `copy` will interpret and remove all double quotes `"` in the last column(s): [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/KpmtMvXW)

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE individuals_raw(
       first_name text, 
       last_name text, 
       location_point_part1 text, 
       location_point_part2 text, 
       location_point_part3 text, 
       location_point_part4 text, 
       location_point_part5 text);

   COPY individuals_raw 
   FROM '/tmp/individuals.csv' CSV HEADER QUOTE '~';

   INSERT INTO individuals (first_name,last_name,location_point)
   SELECT first_name, 
          last_name, 
          ST_MakePoint(
              location_jsonb['geometry']['coordinates'][0]::float
             ,location_jsonb['geometry']['coordinates'][1]::float ) as location_point
   FROM (SELECT first_name, 
                last_name, 
                concat_ws(',',location_point_part1,
                              location_point_part2,
                              location_point_part3,
                              location_point_part4,
                              location_point_part5)::jsonb as location_jsonb
         FROM individuals_raw) a;
   ```

   This can potentially break if your `location_point` field structure isn't constant throughout the file.
2. More robust: surround your `location_point` field with single quotes and add [`quote $$'$$`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.6) or `quote ''''` parameter to the `copy` command. Replace the comma `,` delimiter with semicolon `;` and add `delimiter ';'` parameter: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNMufL57)

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE individuals_raw(
     first_name text, 
     last_name text, 
     location_point jsonb);

   COPY individuals_raw(first_name, last_name, location_point) 
   FROM 'path/to/individuals.csv' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' QUOTE '''';

   INSERT INTO individuals (first_name,last_name,location_point)
   SELECT first_name, 
          last_name, 
          ST_MakePoint(
              location_point['geometry']['coordinates'][0]::float
             ,location_point['geometry']['coordinates'][1]::float ) as location_point
   FROM individuals_raw;
   ```

   The substitution can be done with `sed`, as an example:

   ```bash
   sed -i -e 's/,/;/1' -e "s/,\(.*\)$/;'\1'/1" /tmp/individuals.csv
   ```

   The `1` at the end of the pattern means it's replacing the first comma found in a line. After the first replacement, second comma becomes the first one, so the second pattern is also targetting the first find and replaces it, but also surrounds everything until the end of the line with single quotes.